# loading="lazy" doesn't work in iframes, and data is fetched immediately when page finish loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, lazy-loading

In a website I'm working on I have 3 embedded youtube iframes that are offscreen. I put loading="lazy" on all of them to optimize my website. I have latest chrome version with all necessary flags enabled. All have width and height and are not hidden with any css. But when the main page loads up, all the scripts and data related to the videos are immediately fetched, even before scrolling down to them. Anyone has an idea why it happens?

```
const Videos = () => {
    return (
        <div className="row pt-5 pb-5">
            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <iframe className="offset-sm-1 col-sm-10" width="560" height="315" src="..." loading="lazy" frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen title="" rel="noopener noreferrer"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <iframe className="offset-sm-1 col-sm-10" width="560" height="315" src="..." loading="lazy" frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen title="" rel="noopener noreferrer"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <iframe className="offset-sm-1 col-sm-10" width="560" height="315" src="..." loading="lazy" frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen title="" rel="noopener noreferrer"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: How far off the screen are they? Perhaps they're within the zone to be loaded?

Comment: @evolutionxbox check for yourself :) - https://angela-belly-dancing.web.app

Comment: Is that link SFW?

Comment: The threshold changes based on the connection. https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/ (on chrome). The smallest threshold is 1250px below the viewport. The videos are only 713px away from the bottom of a 1080p viewport.

Comment: (Sorry, just checking. I don't tend to trust random links. It wouldn't be the first time on SO)

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, I appreciate your answers. I guessed there was a threshold but I couldn't find it. It's a shame I can't use this awesome feature, maybe I can lazy load it using a different approach or find a workaround to make it think it reaches the threshold. I guess at some point I'll have enough content to add and meet the threshold requirements.

Comment: If you're using react, consider looking into `react-lazyload`